# Make Image menu highlighted when hovering on its subitem

Tags: html, css, menu

Is it possible to make the image menu keep highlighted when hovering on its subitem? I have 5 navigation menu items but only has has a dropdown. Everytime I hover on subitems of `About Us`(which the one I'm taking about), the `About Us` image turns back to it's original image.

[**JFiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/acott/y2BtT/)

Is there a workaround for this? My friend says it is not possibe, but I'm not fully convinced.

**And this is my code (for reference)**

```
<html>
<head>

<title>CTI | About us</title>

<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
function over(me){
me2=me;
if(me=='about'){
$('#id_About').attr('src','images/hover-aboutus.jpg');}else{$('#id_About').attr('src','images/aboutus.jpg');}

if(me=='partners') {
$('#id_Partners').attr('src','images/hover-partners.jpg');}else{$('#id_Partners').attr('src','images/partners.jpg');}

if(me=='products'){
$('#id_Products').attr('src','images/hover-products.jpg');}else{$('#id_Products').attr('src','images/products.jpg');}

if(me=='contactus'){
$('#id_Contactus').attr('src','images/hover-contactus.jpg');}else{$('#id_Contactus').attr('src','images/contactus.jpg');}
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
 me2='about'; 
$('#id_About').attr('src','images/hover-aboutus.jpg');
});

</script>  


<style type="text/css">
img {
border: 0;
}
a { text-style:none; }
body {text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#wrapper { width:830px; margin:0 auto; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="data2" type="hidden" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['data2'])){echo $_POST['data2']; }else{} ?>">
<div  id="wrapper">
<table width="830px" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 >

<tr>
     <td valign="top" align="left"><a href="aboutus1.php"><img src="images/cti-logo.png" /></a></td>

     <td valign="bottom" align="right">
<a href="welcome.php">
    <img  src="images/home.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-home.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/home.jpg'"/>
<a href="aboutus1.php" class="menu" target="content">
    <img id="id_About" onclick="over('about')" src="images/aboutus.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-aboutus.jpg'" onmouseout="if(me2=='about'){}else{this.src='images/aboutus.jpg'}" />
</a>
<a target="content" href="partners.php">
    <img onclick="over('partners')" id="id_Partners" src="images/partners.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-partners.jpg'" onmouseout="if(me2=='partners'){}else{this.src='images/partners.jpg'}" />
</a>
<a href="products1_1.php" target="content">
    <img onclick="over('products')" id="id_Products" src="images/products.jpg"  onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-products.jpg'" onmouseout=" if(me2=='products'){}else{this.src='images/products.jpg'}" />
</a>
<a href="contactus.php" target="content">
    <img id="id_Contactus" onclick="over('contactus')" src="images/contactus.jpg"  onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-contactus.jpg'" onmouseout=" if(me2=='contactus'){}else{this.src='images/contactus.jpg'}" class="contactus" />
</a>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<!--td colspan="2" class="bar"><img src="images/cti-upperbar.jpg" /></td-->
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<img src="images/cti-upperbar.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED**

I'd like to thank you all for all the efforts. :) 
 I did your suggestions and followed the Fiddle format but there's no image on menu showing :( Still stucked. :(

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>CTI | About us</title>

<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script type="text/css">
.btn1{
    width: 85px;
    height: 58px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
}

.btn1{
    background: url("images/home.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.btn1:hover{
    background: url("images/hover-home.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.btn2{
    width: 85px;
    height: 58px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
}
.btn2{
    background: url("images/aboutus.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.btn2:hover{
    background: url("images/hover-aboutus.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.btn3{
    width: 85px;
    height: 58px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
}
.btn3{
    background: url("images/partners.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.btn3:hover{
    background: url("images/hover-partners.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.btn4{
    width: 85px;
    height: 58px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
}
.btn4{
    background: url("images/products.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.btn4:hover{
    background: url("images/hover-products.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.btn5{
    width: 85px;
    height: 58px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
}
.btn5{
    background: url("images/contactus.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.btn5:hover {
    background: url("images/hover-contactus.jpg") no-repeat;
}
.menu ul li:hover .btn {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style:none;
}
.menu
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}
.menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
    background:#17c0fa;
    width:100px;
    color:#fff;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    line-height:20px;

}
.menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
.menu ul li:hover .btn {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('li').hover(function(){

        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn();
    },function(){
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div  id="wrapper"-->
<table width="830px" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 >

<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><a href="aboutus1.php"><div style="width:85px;height:58px;"></div></a></td>

    <td valign="bottom" align="right">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li href="welcome.php" class="btn1"><img src="images/home.jpg" onmouseover="images/hover-home.jpg" onmouseout="images.home.jpg" /></li>
                <li class="btn2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="aboutus1.php">About CTI</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus2.php">Our Clients</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus3.php">Mission / Vision</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li href="partners.php" class="btn3"></li>
                <li href="products.php" class="btn4"></li>
                <li href="contactus.php" class="btn5"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>

<div class="clear"></div>
</tr>


</tr>
</table-->
</table>
</div>
<img src="images/cti-upperbar.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

I also removed the JS since css is easier than my recent js.

Comment: I don't see any sub items on the page you linked. But before you even get to the sub-menu, you should think about getting rid of all that unnecessary JavaScript. Watch you are trying to do is possible,  without all that unnecessary JavaScript: Start [here with CSS menu w/hover](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/) and then go [here and learn about css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: Actually I edited a JFiddle for that

`http://jsfiddle.net/acott/y2BtT/`

Comment: OK, I see in your fiddle you're using CSS.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/88/

Comment: WAAAAY too much bad JS in here. Specifically all the "onclick", "onmouseover", "onmouseout" events with logic embedded in your JS. Since you are using jQuery you can move all of that out of your markup.

Comment: Basically, the main purpose of JS is for the active image menu.. After 2 days of coding, it's what I ended up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/91/

Answer (score 1):

Going off of your fiddle (please stick with that method, not JavaScript!)

Remove the button and just add the class to you `li`.  When you hover over the `li`, you can move into it's child elements and still be over the `li` but when you hover over the `<div>` and move into the `<ul>` you are no longer within the `<div>`.

Remove `position:absolute` and `margin-top:90px` from you sub-menu.  Everything should work now.

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="btn">HOVER
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

```css
.menu ul li ul{
  display:none;
  background:#78a802;
  width:200px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:90px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/89/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something in the submenu with `hover function`
You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yuhua/jJK2n/ ?

Comment: i forgot to remove the mark of `display:none` in the `li ul {}`, you can remove yourself.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem the only thing you will need to do is add another CSS rule. When you hover over the menu items to keep the changed image.

```
.menu ul li:hover .btn {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/y2BtT/90/)**

You can tell you to your friend that he **lost** cause everything is possible in Web Development the thing is how much time and effort you are willing to spend for it :D

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Answer:

In your CSS just replace...

```
.btn:hover{
```

**with**

```
.menu li:hover .btn {
```

**Demo of your example:**http://jsfiddle.net/y2BtT/94/

**For Inspiration Check out the demo i made: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/FtPvf/1/**

Comment: How am I going to insert the image of Home menu instead of text?

Comment: I edited it first on Fiddle but when I uploaded it in the domain, the image menu doesn't show up.